# Using UIAlertAction with image instead of text

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I want to create a star rating selection component based UIAlertController. My current approach is

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                             message:@"Minimum Rating"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@""
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
[ok setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starRating_1"] forKey:@"image"];

UIAlertAction* ok2 = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@""
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
[ok setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starRating_2"] forKey:@"image"];

UIAlertAction* ok3 = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@""
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
[ok setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starRating_3"] forKey:@"image"];

[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:ok2];
[view addAction:ok3];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Unfortunately the image gets displayed on the left an an accessory view. Is there any way of using the image in place of the AlertAction title?

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem. Did you solved this ?

Comment: unfortunately not. Still doing researches and waiting for an answer, if you find anything please be sure to post it here. Thanks